# Separar string por un patrón

Tags: python, string, split

Tengo el siguiente string:

```
seq = 'ACGACACAGCATCGCGAATTCCCATCGCATTATGATTGA'
```

y necesito un código en Python que reconozca el motivo o patrón G*AATTC para que me lo separe en dos partes, es decir:
ACGACACAGCATCGCG + AATTCCCATCGCATTATGATTGA

Con el siguiente código me separa la cadena, pero omite el patrón AATT:

```
print(re.split('AATT', seq))
```

¿Puede por favor alguien guiarme hacía el resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El patrón sería `"(.+G*)(AATTC.*)`, que reconoce y separa en dos partes el string.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(.+)(G*AATTC.*)")
seq = 'ACGACACAGCATCGCGAATTCCCATCGCATTATGATTGA'

m = patron.findall(seq)
print(m)
```

produce:

```
[('ACGACACAGCATCGCG', 'AATTCCCATCGCATTATGATTGA')]

Process finished with exit code 0
```